# Is it possible to write a MySQL query that loops?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, I want to sum the value (personal_score) for ALL users on the same_team and temporarily assign it to the team_name, and then order them from highest to lowest, and finally only get the highest 10...

```
User
    - int id
    - varchar team_name
    - int personal_score

Team
   - int id
   - varchar team_name
```

So if that makes sense... the result would be something like...

```
   team_name   summed_score
   Chicago     92
   RedBulls    90
   Knights     82
```

Where summed_score is the SUM of ALL personal_score values in the User table that has a team_name equal to each team_name in the Team table.

Right now I do this like so using PHP, but I want to do it purely on the SQL level... Note I'm using medoo.php to query the database in php.

```
function ComparePersonalScores($a, $b)
{
    return $b["total_score"] - $a["total_score"];
}

// Get all the Team Names possible...
$Teams = $Database->select("teams", "team_name");
$TeamResult_Objects = [];
foreach($Teams as $team)
{
    $total_score = $Database->query("SELECT SUM(personal_score) as 'summed_score' FROM users WHERE team_name='" . $team . "';")->fetchAll();

    $result_object["total_score"] = $total_score[0]["summed_score"];
    $result_object["name"] = $team;
    array_push($TeamResult_Objects, $result_object);
}

usort($TeamResult_Objects, "ComparePersonalScores");
$TeamResult_Objects = array_slice($TeamResult_Objects, 0, 10);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Put in your SQL and someone can help you

Comment: Based on you sample result, `SELECT team_name, SUM(score) FROM user GROUP BY team_name;` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to loop. just use sql builtins:
Example:

```
SELECT team_name, SUM(personal_score) AS summed_score FROM User GROUP BY team_name ORDER BY summed_score DESC LIMIT 10;
```

- SUM to sum up the personal score
- GROUP BY to group by team
- ORDER BY to sort
- LIMIT to limit the results

Comment: I completely forgot about GROUP BY... Thank you!